# Need guidance on re-write this batch script in windows to eliminate the characters I want from file names

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, rename

This script above removes the letter A in front of all file names.

```
@echo off
  for %%a in (A*.*) do ren "A*" "/*"
```

Let's say I want to get rid of the last few letters of files names (2 or more characters)  For example, for a file called dinnermenu_FR, I want to get rid of _FR or FR in file names.

```
@echo off
  for %%a in (*.*_FR) do ren "*FR" "/*"
```

If I want to keep the underscore but get rid of characters after it, how should I rewrite this?

Comment: What is the programing language in your example?

Comment: echo, for windows, so bash? Sorry just a beginner.

Comment: It does not look like a shell script to me.

Comment: The code in the question is all MS-Windows .bat file  syntax. Nothing to do with `bash`. Add a proper tag and the experts will look at your question. Good luck.

Comment: Is the `_FR` part of the filename or part of the extension? (judging by your code it's part of the extension) Do the files even have an extension? (according to your example it has not). Please clarify.

Comment: @stephan I apologize,  _FR is the filename, I randomly made. All files are jpg or gif.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
REM for each matching file do...
for %%a in (*_FR.*) do (
  REM get the part of the filename before the underscore...
  for /f "delims=_" %%b in ("%%~na") do (
    REM rename the file...
    ECHO ren "%%a" "%%b%%~xa"
  )
)
```

I commented each line, so you should be able to understand the code. For help with the modifiers `%%~..`, see `for /?`.
I also "disarmed" the `ren` command by just echoing it. Remove the `ECHO` after troubleshooting, when you are sure, it does what you want.

Comment: dumb question, are all those in a loop? The comments are only the REM par right?

Comment: yes, `REM` is a comment (derived from "remark"). See `rem /?`. A `for` loop starts with `for .... do (` and ends with the corresponding `)` (well, that's technically not accurate, but will do for now)

Comment: It doesn't seem to working when I saved as bat file and run it. Should I just run part of the script?

Comment: You said the script is a loop to get rid of before the underscore?

Comment: I want to get rid of every _FR in every file names, at the end of file name.

Comment: I said "*get* the part before the underscore", not "*get rid of* it". Sorry, I spotted a typo and a minor logical failure. Try the edited code please.

Comment: it still didn't work when I saved as a .bat scritpt and run it

Comment: `didn't work` isn't very helpful. What exactly is wrong? (random guess: add `cd /d "%~dp0"` as first line)

Comment: Hey I'm sorry, I just save the script as a bat in notepad, and put in the same folder with all the images. And when I clicked the bat file, nothing happened, unlike other scripts before.

Comment: for troubleshooting don't run per doubleclick. Open a `cmd` window and run it from there.